# EF Core audits for cascade deleted values

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, audit

I have an audit mechanism for a project built with ef-core code first approach. I've set the "DeleteBehavior" property to cascade for some tables in "OnModelCreating" function. When I delete an entity, the other one deleted automaticly by cascade delete behavior. That's all good for now and I need to get all deleted entities, but I cannot. The ChangeTracker doesn't contain the cascade deleted entities. How can I get the cascade deleted values? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Well, you can grab the entities from the database, but that totally defeats the purpose of cascaded deletes. Bottom line is: a client application can't ever audit what happens in the database only. [Only the database can](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cascade Delete happen on the database side. Entity Framework doesn't need to be aware which entity will be deleted.

Entity Framework only tracks changes and delete the base object.

**Edit**: Answer subquestions

You are right. I'm the owner of EF+.

Technically, a library could handle this, but this will come with a severe performance drawback. I'm not aware of any feature or library which handle the cascade delete scenario for auditing.

Suggestion?

There is some suggestion, but I'm pretty sure you will not like any of them, and I don't either recommend them for performance reason:

- Do not use cascade delete (force you also retrieving/deleting related entities)
- Create ON DELETE Trigger and Log at database side.

I don't think a good solution exists for this scenario.

Comment: I assume that you are the creator of EF+ am I right? So, is there a possible way to handle this situation with your library? If not, what would you suggest?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is very helpful :)